# Deserialising 'time' JSON field

Tags: apex

I have a JSON response where one of the field names is "time" in the response.
However in apex the time name is reserved.

How can i save the JSON response to a field?

I have tried this in the RESTResponse object I am deserializing into but no luck

```
@JsonProperty('time')  
public String transactionTime;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices

### Option 1 - Preprocess the JSON (typically, my solution)

- Change your Apex property name to something like `timeX`
- use String class method `replace` to change all references in the inbound JSON body from `"time":` to `"timeX":`
- Deserialize normally

### Option 2 -- deserialize untyped into a Map

- Use [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) `deserializeUntyped(jsonInput)`
- Using the doc example ...

  ```
  Map<String, Object> m = 
   (Map<String, Object>)
      JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
  ```
- then, depending on how your inbound Json is structured, you'll traverse the map and pluck out the `time` field using the Map class's `get` method. [The doc example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) shows this clearly

Comment: Ah did't even think of replacing the string value in the JSON, will give it a try i'm sure it'll work. Thanks!